# Circular Linked list is crashing while trying to print

Tags: c, loops, pointers, linked-list

So I'm working on a program, that will eventually simulate a lame version of duck duck goose (actually called duck duck boot by the professor). When I read the problem circular linked list is what popped out towards me. Though I am very new at using linked lists in general.

It seems like the program is creating and assigning the nodes, but I crash when I try to print them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    struct jimmysFriend *next;
} jimmysFriend;

jimmysFriend *createNode();
void populateList(jimmysFriend *bestFriend, int numberOfFriends);
//void duckDuckBoot();
void printList(jimmysFriend *bestFriend);

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int cases;
    int numberOfFriends;
    scanf("%d", &cases);
    for (i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &numberOfFriends);
        jimmysFriend *bestFriend; //head
        bestFriend = NULL;
        populateList(bestFriend, numberOfFriends);
        printList(bestFriend);
    }
    return 0;
}

void populateList(jimmysFriend *bestFriend, int numberOfFriends) {
    int i; //Where I actually create the circular list.
    jimmysFriend *aFriend;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfFriends; i++) {
        aFriend = createNode();
        if (bestFriend == NULL) {
            bestFriend = aFriend;
            aFriend->next = aFriend;
        } else
        if (bestFriend != NULL) {
            jimmysFriend *temptr;
            aFriend->next = bestFriend;
            temptr = bestFriend;
            while (temptr->next != bestFriend) {
                temptr = temptr->next;
            }
            temptr->next = aFriend;
        }
    }
}

jimmysFriend *createNode() { //Creates a node
    jimmysFriend *aFriend;
    aFriend = malloc(sizeof(jimmysFriend));
    if (aFriend != NULL) {
        scanf("%s", aFriend->name);
    }
    return aFriend;
}

void printList(jimmysFriend *bestFriend) { //Problem area?
    jimmysFriend *temptr;
    temptr = bestFriend;
    while (temptr->next != bestFriend) {
        printf("%s\n", temptr->name);
        temptr = temptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: One obvious problem is the case where the linked list only contains 1 item. In that case, `populateList` sets `bestFriend = aFriend;` and `aFriend->next = aFriend;`. Which means that the `while` loop in `printList` will end without printing anything. In general, it seems that the `while` loop will print one less entry than the list has.

Comment: @user3386109 I see what your saying makes sense, would it be a decent fix to just have an if statement that checks the case that the list only contains one item in the `printList` ?

Comment: 2 things I noticed: 1) `typedef struct` - > `typedef struct jimmysFriends` 2) `aFriend = malloc(sizeof(jimmysFriend));` - > `aFriend = (jimmysFriend*)malloc(sizeof(jimmysFriend));`

Comment: I just tried your code and for some reason it doesn't print at all. Whereever I try to print something it just ignores it.

Comment: @Jude I think this is a case where you're forced to use a `do {} while` loop. The body of the loop should print a node and then advance the pointer to the next node. Then the `while` part checks to see if you've reached the beginning of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

The first is that you're not passing `bestFriend` to `populateList()` by address, so it doesn't get changed. `populateList()` should look like this:

```
void populateList(jimmysFriend **bestFriend, int numberOfFriends){
    int i; //Where I actually create the circular list.
    jimmysFriend* aFriend;
    for(i = 0; i < numberOfFriends; i++){
        aFriend = createNode();
        if(*bestFriend == NULL){
            *bestFriend = aFriend;
            aFriend->next = aFriend;
        }
        else if(*bestFriend != NULL){
            jimmysFriend* temptr;
            aFriend->next = *bestFriend;
            temptr = *bestFriend;
            while(temptr->next != *bestFriend){
                temptr = temptr-> next;
            }
            temptr->next = aFriend;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you call it like this:

```
populateList(&bestFriend, numberOfFriends);
```

The second problem is that your condition for the `printList()` loop is wrong. There is more than one way of writing it, but this `do` loop works:

```
void printList(jimmysFriend* bestFriend){ //Problem area?
    if (bestFriend != NULL) {
        jimmysFriend* temptr = bestFriend;
        do {
            printf("%s\n", temptr->name);
            temptr = temptr->next;
        } while (temptr != bestFriend);
    }
}
```

Reference: [Circular Linked List](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/circular-linked-list.html)

Comment: I always thought that just passing into a function by reference would let me change the original variable. So if my original variable is a pointer to be able to have it keep the changes made from a function I have to make it a double pointer?

Also why Is my loop condition wrong? As I'm not sure what was actually wrong with it. But your suggestions do work! Thanks!

Comment: Jude see @user3386109's comment for why your loop doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In populateList() Jimmy's best friend isn't really pointed at the head of the list   when you are done with the function. The assignment that you make in populateList() is lost.

Pass jimmy's best friend as the address of the pointer to the function. So populateList() will accept jimmysFriend **bestFriend. Then when you try to store the head there you will assign the node you want to be the head to *bestFriend.

You can always validate that by checking if Jimmy's best friend is NULL right before you call printList().

```
populateList ( &bestFriend, numberOfFriends);
```